# SQL using a variable SQL query within another variable SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I've created a variable SQL query, where I declare the SQL query I want to use, due to variable table names. Our SQL is set up, based on an account name in the system. Meaning that it looks somewhat like this: `[LSRetail].[dbo].[AccountName$Item]`.

Here the `LSRetail` part is dynamic, since it is called `LSRetailDK` if it's Denmark, and `LSRetailSE` if it's Sweden. The `AccountName` is also dynamic, due to different store names and zip codes...

All this actually works and is declared and set to `@Sql`, but due to space, I would like to make another `DECLARE @Sql2 VARCHAR(8000)`, in which I want to `SELECT * FROM @Sql`. Since `@Sql` starts with a `with cte1 AS (` statement, it wont allow me to do this.

Is it possible to do something here? I would like to combine the two in `@Sql2` or maybe in an `@Sql3`.
Right now, the only thing that works is `SET @Sql2 = @Sql` and executing that.

The code below, is the code for `@Sql` of which I want to use inside `@Sql2`.

```
DECLARE @OrderNo VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @StoreName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table2 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table3 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table4 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table5 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table6 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table7 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table8 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table9 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Database VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @BulkDiscount VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @DisclaimerDiscount VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @CashDiscount VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Loyalty VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Orders VARCHAR(8000);


SET @Database = '[LSRetail]'
SET @StoreName = 'AccountName';
SET @Orders = '''TI0573057'', ''TI0572704'', ''TI0572541'', ''TI0573058'', ''TI0572983'', ''TI0572595'', ''TI0573516'', ''TI0572841'', ''TI0573175'', ''TI0572759'', ''TI0572861'', ''TI0572917'', ''TI0568408'', ''TI0573077'', ''TI0572641'', ''TI0570757'', ''TI0573419'', ''TI0573394'', ''TI0572893'', ''TI0573029'', ''TI0573317'', ''TI0572581'', ''TI0570652'', ''TI0573061'', ''TI0573340'', ''TI0572417'', ''TI0572769'', ''TI0573315'', ''TI0572975'', ''TI0573304'', ''TI0573381'', ''TI0572976'', ''TI0572862'', ''TI0572886'', ''TI0573615'', ''TI0573049'', ''TI0572811'', ''TI0573156'', ''TI0573222'', ''TI0573095'', ''TI0573023''';

SET @BulkDiscount = 2.5/100
SET @DisclaimerDiscount = 1.5/100
SET @CashDiscount = 0.0/100
SET @Loyalty = 5.3/100

SET @Table1 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Invoice Line]');
SET @Table2 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Invoice Header]');
SET @Table3 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Item]');
SET @Table4 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Cr_Memo Line]');
SET @Table5 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Cr_Memo Header]');
SET @Table6 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Inv_ Header]');
SET @Table7 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Inv_ Line]');
SET @Table8 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Cr_ Memo Hdr_]');
SET @Table9 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Cr_ Memo Line]');

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(8000);
SET @Sql =
'
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT a.[Document No_]
      ,''Invoice'' AS [Document Type]
      ,b.[Unique Document No_]
      ,a.[Type]
      ,a.[No_]
      ,c.[Vendor Item No_]
      ,a.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Bus_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[Description]
      ,a.[Item Order Group Code]
      ,a.[Quantity]
      ,a.[Unit of Measure]
      ,a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]
      ,a.[Unit Price]
      ,a.[Line Amount]
      ,a.[Line Discount %]
      ,a.[Line Amount]/(a.[VAT %]/100+1)*0.96 AS [Total Line Sales]
      ,CASE WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @DisclaimerDiscount + ') * (1-' + @BulkDiscount + ') * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] LIKE ''%99999''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
       END AS [Total Line Cost]
FROM ' + @Table1 + ' a
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table2 + ' b ON a.[Document No_] = b.[No_]
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table3 + ' c ON a.[No_] = c.[No_]
WHERE b.[Prepayment Invoice] = 0
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT a.[Document No_]
      ,''Credit Memo'' AS [Document Type]
      ,b.[Unique Document No_]
      ,a.[Type]
      ,a.[No_]
      ,c.[Vendor Item No_]
      ,a.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Bus_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[Description]
      ,a.[Item Order Group Code]
      ,a.[Quantity] * (-1) AS [Quantity]
      ,a.[Unit of Measure]
      ,a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]
      ,a.[Unit Price]
      ,a.[Line Amount]
      ,a.[Line Discount %]
      ,a.[Line Amount]/(a.[VAT %]/100+1)*0.96 AS [Total Line Sales]
      ,CASE WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @DisclaimerDiscount + ') * (1-' + @BulkDiscount + ') * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] LIKE ''%99999''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
       END AS [Total Line Cost]
FROM ' + @Table4 + ' a
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table5 + ' b ON a.[Document No_] = b.[No_]
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table3 + ' c ON a.[No_] = c.[No_]
WHERE b.[Prepayment Credit Memo] = 0
),
cte3 AS(
SELECT *
FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM cte2
)
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN [Total Line Sales] <> 0
            THEN ([Total Line Sales] - [Total Line Cost])
            ELSE 0
       END AS [Margin]
      ,CASE WHEN [Total Line Sales] <> 0
            THEN ([Total Line Sales] - [Total Line Cost])/[Total Line Sales]
            ELSE 0
       END AS [Margin %]
FROM cte3
WHERE [No_] <> ''''
AND [Unique Document No_] IN (' + @Orders + ')
ORDER BY [Unique Document No_], [Item Order Group Code]
'
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Note: I use SQL Server.

Comment: Why don't you paste a sample code and expected output. I think it would be far easy to understand than your text.

Comment: @JaimeDrq it has now been added to it - It's a long code :)

Comment: This feels like you need to be fixing your design, not the SQL. Having a different table for each store is why you're having a problem. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: The issue is that this won't be fixed until we get an upgrade of the system, which can handle it. This might take a couple of years, and we need this solution now :P

Comment: *"The issue is that this won't be fixed until we get an upgrade of the system, which can handle it."* The system you have at the moment will be slower because of the design, so if it can handle the design you have now, it'll easily be able to handle a well designed, and normalised, database.

Comment: *Side Note:* Code like `[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Invoice Line]` is **not** injection proof. A value like `'MyTable]; DROP TABLE dbo.MyTable];--` would still inject. If you must inject object names, use `QUOTENAME`. **Never** inject unsanitised strings into your dynamic queries.

Comment: Oh well, that's just what I've been told anyway :)

I'm just using MSSQL, in order to modify some data and get it into Excel, since I'm a controller. I don't control the design of the database, I'm just using it :)

Comment: If you need to create dynamic statement, you needs to create them in full. Trying to concatenate statements that were created for different purposes, without chnaging them, rarely works well, if at all (example here). You'll need to rewrite the statement completely for the task you want. Dyanmic Statement **can** include a CTE, so it starting with a `WITH` makes no difference.

Comment: You also **must** parametrise your statements too  (I *cannot* stress ***MUST*** more). `' + @DisclaimerDiscount + '` is a ***very*** bad idea. Comments are not the place to be telling you how to code properly, without huge security flaws, so please do take the time to read an article I wrote on the [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql)

Comment: Can you simplified your requirement with a small sample code rather than actual query ? It is too much to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem...

By removing the last `SELECT` statement, I was able to use it in a second variable.

```
DECLARE @OrderNo VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @StoreName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @Table1 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table2 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table3 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table4 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table5 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table6 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table7 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table8 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Table9 VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Database VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @BulkDiscount VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @DisclaimerDiscount VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @CashDiscount VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Loyalty VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Orders VARCHAR(8000);


SET @Database = '[LSRetail]'
SET @StoreName = 'AccountName';
SET @Orders = '''TI0573057'', ''TI0572704'', ''TI0572541'', ''TI0573058'', ''TI0572983'', ''TI0572595'', ''TI0573516'', ''TI0572841'', ''TI0573175'', ''TI0572759'', ''TI0572861'', ''TI0572917'', ''TI0568408'', ''TI0573077'', ''TI0572641'', ''TI0570757'', ''TI0573419'', ''TI0573394'', ''TI0572893'', ''TI0573029'', ''TI0573317'', ''TI0572581'', ''TI0570652'', ''TI0573061'', ''TI0573340'', ''TI0572417'', ''TI0572769'', ''TI0573315'', ''TI0572975'', ''TI0573304'', ''TI0573381'', ''TI0572976'', ''TI0572862'', ''TI0572886'', ''TI0573615'', ''TI0573049'', ''TI0572811'', ''TI0573156'', ''TI0573222'', ''TI0573095'', ''TI0573023''';

SET @BulkDiscount = 2.5/100
SET @DisclaimerDiscount = 1.5/100
SET @CashDiscount = 0.0/100
SET @Loyalty = 5.3/100

SET @Table1 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Invoice Line]');
SET @Table2 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Invoice Header]');
SET @Table3 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Item]');
SET @Table4 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Cr_Memo Line]');
SET @Table5 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Sales Cr_Memo Header]');
SET @Table6 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Inv_ Header]');
SET @Table7 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Inv_ Line]');
SET @Table8 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Cr_ Memo Hdr_]');
SET @Table9 = CONCAT(@Database,'.[dbo].[','' + @StoreName + '','$Purchase Cr_ Memo Line]');

DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(8000);
SET @Sql =
'
WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT a.[Document No_]
      ,''Invoice'' AS [Document Type]
      ,b.[Unique Document No_]
      ,a.[Type]
      ,a.[No_]
      ,c.[Vendor Item No_]
      ,a.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Bus_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[Description]
      ,a.[Item Order Group Code]
      ,a.[Quantity]
      ,a.[Unit of Measure]
      ,a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]
      ,a.[Unit Price]
      ,a.[Line Amount]
      ,a.[Line Discount %]
      ,a.[Line Amount]/(a.[VAT %]/100+1)*0.96 AS [Total Line Sales]
      ,CASE WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @DisclaimerDiscount + ') * (1-' + @BulkDiscount + ') * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] LIKE ''%99999''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
       END AS [Total Line Cost]
FROM ' + @Table1 + ' a
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table2 + ' b ON a.[Document No_] = b.[No_]
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table3 + ' c ON a.[No_] = c.[No_]
WHERE b.[Prepayment Invoice] = 0
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT a.[Document No_]
      ,''Credit Memo'' AS [Document Type]
      ,b.[Unique Document No_]
      ,a.[Type]
      ,a.[No_]
      ,c.[Vendor Item No_]
      ,a.[Gen_ Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Bus_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[VAT Prod_ Posting Group]
      ,a.[Description]
      ,a.[Item Order Group Code]
      ,a.[Quantity] * (-1) AS [Quantity]
      ,a.[Unit of Measure]
      ,a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]
      ,a.[Unit Price]
      ,a.[Line Amount]
      ,a.[Line Discount %]
      ,a.[Line Amount]/(a.[VAT %]/100+1)*0.96 AS [Total Line Sales]
      ,CASE WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @DisclaimerDiscount + ') * (1-' + @BulkDiscount + ') * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] LIKE ''%99999''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] <> ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity] * (1-' + @CashDiscount + ') * (1-' + @Loyalty + ')
            WHEN a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''SM%'' OR a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''LE%'' AND a.[No_] NOT LIKE ''%99999'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00100'' AND a.[Item Order Group Code] = ''OVT00500''
            THEN a.[Unit Cost (LCY)]*a.[Quantity]
       END AS [Total Line Cost]
FROM ' + @Table4 + ' a
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table5 + ' b ON a.[Document No_] = b.[No_]
LEFT JOIN ' + @Table3 + ' c ON a.[No_] = c.[No_]
WHERE b.[Prepayment Credit Memo] = 0
),
cte3 AS(
SELECT *
FROM cte1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM cte2
)
'
@DECLARE @Sql2 VARCHAR(8000);
SET @Sql2 =
@Sql + '
SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN [Total Line Sales] <> 0
            THEN ([Total Line Sales] - [Total Line Cost])
            ELSE 0
       END AS [Margin]
      ,CASE WHEN [Total Line Sales] <> 0
            THEN ([Total Line Sales] - [Total Line Cost])/[Total Line Sales]
            ELSE 0
       END AS [Margin %]
FROM cte3
WHERE [No_] <> ''''
AND [Unique Document No_] IN (' + @Orders + ')
ORDER BY [Unique Document No_], [Item Order Group Code]
'
```